# Joint probability of two random variables both following poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this joint probability question I'm having trouble with. If X, Y follow a poisson distribution with Poisson($\lambda$) and X and Y are independent. Show that:
$$1 \le \frac{VAR(max{X,Y})}{\lambda} \le 2$$

I know that variance of a random variable following a poisson distribution is $\lambda$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hint: the cdf for the maximum is just the product of the cdf’s for the individual rv’s. Just multiply the two CDF's and I am sure you can calculate the variance of $max(X,Y)$.

Comment: @jay: I doubt that.  Can you?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I see your point here.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, it is always true that for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (independent or not), $\text{Var}(\max(X,Y)) + \text{Var}(\min(X,Y)) \le \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)$.  This gives you the upper bound.  I don't see an easy way to get the lower bound.